# Spring Boot Application with S/4Hana On-Premise using Cloud SDK 3.9.0

Tags: sdk, cloud, cloud-foundry, sap-cloud-platform, s4hana

I am trying to write a Spring Boot application (Gradle), which will query data via cloud connector from a S/4Hana on-premise system.

Just fyi:
I already  have Java (Maven) application (example from SAP) running, which is working fine. So my cloud setup should be o.k.

When I deploy the Spring Boot application to the Cloud Foundry, I get this error message:

```
   2019-12-18T13:58:34.26+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT ***************************
   2019-12-18T13:58:34.26+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT APPLICATION FAILED TO START
   2019-12-18T13:58:34.26+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT ***************************
   2019-12-18T13:58:34.26+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Description:
   2019-12-18T13:58:34.26+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:
   2019-12-18T13:58:34.26+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.connectivity.ScpCfDestinationLoader.<clinit>(ScpCfDestinationLoader.java:53)
   2019-12-18T13:58:34.26+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT The following method did not exist:
   2019-12-18T13:58:34.26+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.cache.CacheManager.register(Lcom/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/Cache;)Lcom/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/Cache;
   2019-12-18T13:58:34.26+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT The method's class, com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.cache.CacheManager, is available from the following locations:
   2019-12-18T13:58:34.26+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/caching-2.22.0.jar!/com/sap/cloud/sdk/cloudplatform/cache/CacheManager.class
   2019-12-18T13:58:34.26+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/caching-3.9.0.jar!/com/sap/cloud/sdk/cloudplatform/cache/CacheManager.class
   2019-12-18T13:58:34.26+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT It was loaded from the following location:
   2019-12-18T13:58:34.26+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     jar:file:/home/vcap/app/BOOT-INF/lib/caching-2.22.0.jar!/
   2019-12-18T13:58:34.26+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Action:
   2019-12-18T13:58:34.26+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.cache.CacheManager
   2019-12-18T13:58:34.39+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 1
```

My Spring Boot application class is configured like this:
[image]

I'm using these gradle dependencies:

```
  compile "com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform:scp-cf:3.9.0"
  compile "com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana:s4hana-all:3.9.0"
  compile "com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform:caching:3.9.0"
  compile "com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform:security-servlet:3.9.0"
```

and the manifest.yml looks like this:
[image]

Am I missing some dependencies or is the *.yml wrong?

Answer (score 0):

O.k, I found the cause, but I do not understand, why this is a issue:
If I use:

```
DestinationAccessor.tryGetDestination("myDestination")
```

I get the error! When I try to get the destination with

```
DestinationAccessor.getDestination("myDestination")
```

there is no problem!